# the change of the status bar changes the title of navigation bar in ios. xamarin.forms

Tags: layout, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, statusbar, navigationbar

I am facing a problem Because in my IOS app I need a status bar with white textcolor, and I need a nav bar with a orange title color and a white back button as in the image But with a white status bar:

[image]

For change the status bar color I did it in the app.xaml.cs in the pcl project

```
            MainPage =  new NavigationPage(new Views.Splash2()) { BarTextColor = Color.White };
```

it changed my status bar color as I want but the nav bar title is white know...How can I solve this problem? I need the first photo layout but with a white status bar like the second...

[image]

I am working with xamarin.forms

-----------------------------edit---------------------------

Searching, I know now that the status bar color of ios in xamarin.forms depends of nav bar text color, then, if you use a color that is considered "light" (it need to have a value to blue, that can't be 0) the statubar text color is white, else it is black...
I am using a light orange (which is not the color that I wanted, but it's ok, it's better)...I saw the solution here

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/51602/on-ios-can-i-set-the-statusbar-text-color-independently-of-the-navigationpage-bartextcolor

now, my status bar text is white and my nav bar text is orange, but the problem is: in ios the nav bar back button is orange to when I set this color with

```
            MainPage =  new NavigationPage(new Views.Splash2()) { BarTextColor = Color.FromHex("#ff9e14") };
```

and I need it in white color, as I showed here. 
How it is now:

[image]

How can I change only the nav bar back button color?

Comment: this is now the FOURTH time you've posted about this issue.  Please don't post the same issue multiple times.

Comment: it's other problem....I can change the status bar now, but I can't do it together the change of my nav bar title...

Comment: I can change the nav bar title color as well

Answer (score 0):

It's really complicated to understand, because the status bar color changes only if you change the nav bar text color...if you use "light colors" (with a good quantity of blue), the status bar changes to white, but if you use a color with no blue the statusbar text will be black...Besides that...when you change the nav bar text color of the pages in app.xaml.cs as I showed in my question, in ios, not in android, the back button of the nav bar will have the same color that you setted to the title of the nav bar...if you want a different color for the back button, you can create a custom navigation renderer and inside that use this line

```
            this.NavigationBar.TintColor = UIColor.colorThatYouWant;
```

That is it ! A hell ¬¬'